# How to change the value of column as per predefined percentage applied to selected rows only

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6'], 'pd':[0.6,0.26,0.94,0.44,0.65,0.88]})
df
    cust_id    pd
0      a1     0.60
1      a2     0.26
2      a3     0.99
3      a4     0.44
4      a5     0.65
5      a6     0.88
```

I want shock the pd column as per categories which i define as:

```
def pd_cat(n):
    if n < 0.2:
        return '1'
    elif n >=0.2 and n < 0.4:
        return '2'
    elif n >=0.4 and n < 0.6:
        return '3'
    elif n >=0.6 and n < 0.8:
        return '4'
    else:
        return '5'



df['pd_risk_cat'] =  df['pd'].apply(lambda x: pd_cat(x))

df
    cust_id    pd    pd_cat
0      a1     0.60    4
1      a2     0.26    2
2      a3     0.99    5
3      a4     0.44    3
4      a5     0.65    4
5      a6     0.88    5
```

Then i create a map to shock pd values depending on the pd_cat as :

```
cat_map={'1':1.1, '2':1.2, '3':1.3,'4':1.4,'5':1.5}
df["pd_stressed"]=df["pd"].mul(df["pd_cat"].map(cat_map))
```

But i want to apply the cat_map to only those rows where pd<0.7 and if >=0.7, the value remains same as the original pd value.

How can i achieve this?

Expected output:

```
df
    cust_id    pd    pd_cat  pd_stressed
0      a1     0.60    4       0.84
1      a2     0.26    2       0.312
2      a3     0.99    5       0.99 (sames as original pd value)
3      a4     0.44    3       0.572
4      a5     0.65    4       0.91
5      a6     0.88    5       0.88 (sames as original pd value)
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: have a look at `pd.cut`

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `series.mask`:

```
df["pd_stressed"] = df['pd'].mask(df['pd'].lt(0.9),
                    df["pd"].mul(df["pd_risk_cat"].map(cat_map)))
print(df)
```

---

```
        cust_id    pd pd_risk_cat  pd_stressed
0      a1  0.60           4        0.840
1      a2  0.26           2        0.312
2      a3  0.94           5        0.940   <- This value remains same since  >= 0.9
3      a4  0.44           3        0.572
4      a5  0.65           4        0.910
5      a6  0.88           5        1.320
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for.Thanks alot!!